# butter fat on top of frozen roux. Is it still good to use?

Tags: roux

I made a brown roux and froze some. Now there is a thin layer of butter fat on top of the roux. Is the roux still good? Do I need to remove the butter fat, or just start all over again? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you concerned that butter fat would be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

No problem, just melt it gently over low heat, stirring, and go ahead with whatever you were going to do.